# PowerDNS - DNSQuestion is always nil

Tags: lua, powerdns

I have setup a PowerDNS (4.0.4-1+deb9u4) upon Debian 9 with a MySQL backend successfully and the system was resolving hosts correctly. I am attempting to add scripting to the recursor and have used the examples, [Lua script examples](https://github.com/PowerDNS/pdns/blob/master/pdns/recursordist/contrib/powerdns-example-script.lua). I have pointed the pdns-resolver's conf correctly at my lua script, and I see my log statements print correctly, but I am consistently receiving an error regarding the [DNSQuestion](https://doc.powerdns.com/recursor/lua-scripting/dq.html) instance being empty for all of the example lua functions.

For example:

```
function preresolve(dq)
    pdnslog("Got question for "..dq.qname:toString().." from "..dq.remoteaddr:toString().." to "..dq.localaddr:toString())
    return true;
end
```

Results in :
`STL error (a.root-servers.net/A from 127.0.0.1): Trying to cast a lua variable from "nil" to "b"` (meaning the DNSQuestion instance is null).

Clearly the lua script is running, but for some reason, all the dq instances are empty.

Is there anything that I may have misunderstood or am missing that would cause the parameter to be nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your function return `true` or `false` so it will not return `nil` by default.

Comment: It’s not that the function is returning the wrong type, it’s that the function is receiving the incorrect type.

Comment: @SmittySmee which function? if dq were nil you would face script errors for indexing nil values. all preresolve examples return values

Comment: The function from the example. The parameter, dq, for preresolve function is nil. I have even added a condition check for nil and it meets that condition. Let me know if I am not making sense.

Comment: @SmittySmee if dq is nil the error is not related to the provided code.

Comment: For the `STL error (a.root-servers.net/A from 127.0.0.1): Trying to cast a lua variable from "nil" to "b"` this was due to the non-valid return type. I followed the instructions from building from source and added a few libraries and now am no longer receiving the nil either. I am marking this as the accepted answer as it removes the `STL` error.